# What percentage drop is this?

Tags: statistics, percentages

Can someone help a student who is terribly bad at math answer this question? Between 1998 and 2014, in New Mexico, Birth rates for teens 18-19 years of age fell from a rate of 108.8 per 1000 to 69.3 per 1,000 females. What percentage had the teen birth rate dropped?

So in my mind all of these answers pop up. The figure 69.3 is 44% lower than 108.8. However, when comparing 108.8/1000 to 69.3/1000 the drop between the two is 13.28%. Then again, simply taking 108.8 and subtracting it by 69.3 would give us 39.5.

Comment: Can you show what calculations you are doing that give rise to the numbers 44% and 13.28%?

Comment: I also have no idea how to obtain 44% from those numbers.

Comment: Don't get trapped by wordings. I see it all the times when I take a look at the stock market/financial market. When the interests of a loan raise from 2 percent to three percent, did they raise one percent or 50 percent?

Comment: @Gyro Gearloose: I have added something about that to the end of my answer. The correct wording in that case is that the interest rate rose by 50%, which was an increase of one percentage point. For the newspapers, the change in percentage points is what they would report, not the percent change.

Comment: If you have an understanding of the difference, you can't really be bad at math.

Comment: @CarlMummert xcuse my last comment, I thought you were the original poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous teen birth rate was $108.8/1000$ and the new birth rate was $69.3/1000$.

The percentage decrease is, by definition, the difference between the old and new values, divided by the old value.

In this case, the old birth rate is $108.8/1000$ and the new birth rate is $69.3/1000$. So the percentage decrease is
$$
\frac{\left(\frac{108.8}{1000} - \frac{69.3}{1000} \right)}{\frac{108.8}{1000}},
$$
which simplifies to 
$$
\frac{108.8 - 69.3}{108.8}.
$$
The value of that fraction is about 0.363, so the birth rate decreased by about 36.3%.

The key point is to remember the definition of "percent decrease". It is not merely the amount of decrease (which would be $39.5/1000$).

A sometimes confusing topic is that we can look at the old and new rates as percentages themselves. The old birth rate was $10.88\%$ and the new birth rate is $6.93\%$. If you subtract these, you get a difference of $3.95\%$. That is not the "percent change" - it is just the difference between the percentages. To keep this clear, we say that the birth rate **decreased by $\mathbf{3.95}$ percentage points**. Of course, it also **decreased by $\mathbf{36.3}$ percent**.

Comment: I'm glad you clarified the difference between _amount_ decrease and _percent_ decrease! I have a feeling my teacher isn't aware of the importance of wording either. I will definitely be explaining this concept in my answer to make sure he knows. Thank you!

Comment: One reason that the difference is confusing is that even newspapers don't always get the terminology correct. The bigger ones usually do, because they have someone checking all their stories. But smaller papers may write for example that the unemployment rate went up 0.2 percent when they mean it went up 0.2 percentage points.   In math, though, we try to be precise with our language.

Answer (score 1):

$108.8$ became $69.3$ so what will $100\%$ become? Write

\begin{align}108.8 &\longmapsto 69.3\\ 100\% &\longmapsto x\%\end{align} Can you learn the following rule: Multiply diagonally and equate! $$x\%\cdot108.8=69.3\cdot100\% \implies x\%=\frac{69.3}{108.8}\cdot100\%=63.69\%$$ So $100\%$ will become $63.69\%$ which means that it will be reduced by $100\%-63.69\%=36.31\%$. That is your number.

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense when you put it like that.